# String replace with a third argument mysteriously working

Tags: javascript, replace

I've stumbled upon some unexpected behavior from some code.

```
var c = "\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"";
c.replace(/"|\s/g, "")
```

This outputs the string "a,b,c" as expected.

Later in the code I found

```
var c = "\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"";
c.replace(/"|\s/g, "", "")
```

This also outputs the string "a,b,c" without any errors but I can't find in any documentation String.prototype.replace() taking 3 arguments. The string on the last argument doesn't seem to make any difference whatever it is. What is going on? What am I missing?

Comment: You can call `replace` with 5000 arguments and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked because in JavaScript, extra arguments are just ignored.  Often time in the code, the function will take whatever that is needed, and not use any extra arguments that are passed in, so that's why:

(this is running in NodeJS)

```
> f = (a) => a * a
[Function: f]

> f(2)
4

> f(2, 3)
4
```

It is different from some other languages, such as in Ruby:

```
> f(2)
 => 4

> f(2, 3)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```